# How to move onchange="form.submit()" into script tag?

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

I have the following html:

```
<form id="forum_jump" action="http://www.url.com/index.php?" method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <select name="showforum" id="showforumJump" class="input_select">
                <optgroup label="Redirect">
                    <option value="0">Frontpage</option>
                    <option value="1">Forum 1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;|-- Forum 2</option>
<option value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;|-- Forum 3</option>
<option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;|-- ...</option>

                </optgroup>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="input_submit alt" id="forum_jump_submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I know that I can change the select html to tell it to submit the form when the select is changed with:

```
<select name="showforum" id="showforumJump" class="input_select" onchange="forum_jump.submit()">
```

But how do I translate this into a script block? I've tried to manually run things like the below in the Chrome Dev Console:

```
document.getElementById('showforumJump').addEventListener("change", forum_jump.submit(), false );
```

I tried with attachEvent aswell, before I read that was appearantly just for IE(?).

addEventListener ends with "undefined" being written to console, before the form is immediately resubmitted and page reloaded. I would expect the console to wait for me to change the value of the select before resubmit. I also tried to wrap it inside window.onload when I tried to implement on the site but it just ends with an endless loop.

What am I misunderstanding about the addEventListener and what is going wrong here? I honestly can't see it.

This is probarbly something really simple but I've tried and researched for a while and just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use name (identifier) of the function, not the result of function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
document.getElementById('showforumJump').addEventListener("change", forum_jump.submit(), false );
```

You are binding the "change" event to the output of forum_jump.submit(). Try wrapping it in a function, in case forum_jump.submit() relies on the this symbol:

```
document.getElementById('showforumJump').addEventListener("change", function() { forum_jump.submit.apply(forum_jump, arguments); }, false );
```

This might be overkill for your case, if submit() is called without arguments. You could probably just remove the parenthesis:

```
document.getElementById('showforumJump').addEventListener("change", forum_jump.submit, false );
```

The apply construction is to forward all arguments passed to the function, which is probably not needed here. For an explanation of scoping and the 'this' symbol, see for example:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/04/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thanks, using forum_jump.submit without pharenthesis didn't seem to work or do anything, but I did:
    document.getElementById('showforumJump').addEventListener("change", function(){ forum_jump.submit() }, false ); 

And that worked. I'll do some reading up on this to better understand why and how it works, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably because the forum_jump.submit() method uses the "this" symbol which won't be set correctly if you do the non-parenthesis thing.

Answer (score 2):

forum_jump.submit() should be without () since it's a reference to execute and not the execution itself:

```
document.getElementById('showforumJump').addEventListener("change", forum_jump.submit, false );
```

Comment: Hello, I've gotten it to work now, although the above didn't seem to work me either. But I did this:
       document.getElementById('showforumJump').addEventListener("change", function(){ forum_jump.submit() }, false );